# How to call multiple operations of data service in single proxy service of wso2 esb?

Tags: wso2, esb

I have a data service that contains two queries. One is a select query and the other is an insert query.

How could we call both queries in a single proxy service? Is there any way to call both queries in a single operation or by adding two call mediators in the proxy service?

As I am using call mediator, how can we call different operations? I have tried it by creating two different data services, but it is giving error "Error while building Passthrough stream"

Can any one provide a sample of both?

Source of my Proxy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="EslSfaOfaCreateSaleOrdersPS"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="soap11"
                        uri="http://10.1.6.175:9763/services/EslSfaExtractSODataService.SOAP11Endpoint/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="soap11"
                        uri="http://10.1.6.175:9763/services/EslSfaInsertTempDataService.SOAP11Endpoint/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log level="full"/>
         <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOfaCreateSOMapping.dmc"
                     inputSchema="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOfaCreateSOMapping_inputSchema.json"
                     inputType="XML"
                     outputSchema="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOfaCreateSOMapping_outputSchema.json"
                     outputType="XML"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <header/>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="soap11"
                        uri="https://host/soa-infra/services/default/DooDecompReceiveOrderExternalComposite/ReceiveOrderRequestService"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

The error start coming as i aded second call

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-25 15:08:36,060] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} -  Error while building Passthrough stream {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils}
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found faultstring
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:305)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:252)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createNextOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:234)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:249)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:65)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:148)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:137)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:140)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:83)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:766)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-25 15:08:36,065] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Error while building message {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:284)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:143)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:140)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:83)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:766)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
```

Comment: You can have any number of call mediators inside a proxy

Comment: I think the "[Clone Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Clone+Mediator)" or [Iterate Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Iterate+Mediator) will help you. Noted, these must work with [Aggregate Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Aggregate+Mediator). And i think error "Error while building Passthrough stream" is because you are not build messages properly.

Comment: I have added the source of proxy and error i am facing. whereas it runs successfully if i remove second call.

Comment: please add <log level="full"> after each call mediator to check the response message, in one of that calls you had a fault message...
A question: the response of the first WS call is the input of the second WS call?

Comment: I already have log mediator after each call, the above error is obtained from same log. I just removed to make code a bit simple.
whereas only output of first call in input for the third call, mapped with data mapper. while second call is updating the records in db being fetched in first call.

Comment: put a full log after the first call and update the logs in your question.

Comment: I think your second call expects a valid payload but it is getting a fault

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My first call of endpoint gives the correct output. But second call gives the same error as above. Does anyone know the answer for this?